# ASP.NET MVC 2 VirtualPathProvider GetFile every time for every request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, virtualpathprovider

I have implemented a VirtualPathProvider. The VirtualPathProvider reads the view from File system.

However my problem is the method `GetFile(string virtualPath)` is not executed every time for every request. I think it is related to the caching, isn't it? What I want is **getting file every time for every request**. Because for some cases, the page in the file system will be modified and users want the system shows the changes immediately.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your provider get called every time when in debug mode?  If so, then it's caching, as the view caching is disabled when debug is enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The VirtualPathProvider is called for every request, but only the `bool FileExists(string virtualPath)` method is called for every request. I have tried to override all methods in the VirtualPathProvider, but I still cannot find the solution.

Comment: In fact, I just directly run an example from http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2009/04/virtualpathprovider-example.html.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution myself on the internet.

Really thanks **jbeall** replied on 07-15-2008, 11:05 AM.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1289756.aspx

In short words, overrides the following methods

1. `GetCacheDependency` - always return null
2. `GetFileHash` - always return different value

After these modifications, for every request, MVC gets the file from source directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
{

    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
    {
        return null;

    }

    public override String GetFileHash(String virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies)
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    }
}
```